# MVC 6 vNext Display Name attribute not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

The Display Name attribute not working vNext.

**CustomerEntryModel**

```
public class CustomerEntryModel
{
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerEntry.cshtml**

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@model CustomerEntryModel

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" asp-for="FirstName"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="FirstName">FirstName</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

The following post shows how to use tag helper on the label to print the display name. But, this uses `DisplayAttribute`, which works for me too.

http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc-6-label-tag-helper.aspx

But, I want to use `DisplayNameAttribute`. The reason is, I want to extend the behavior of the attribute, and retrieve the display name from database. I can't extend `DisplayAttribute` because it is sealed.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you use Razor syntax and the `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName )` helper?

Comment: It's not working even with Razor syntax, and that's obvious, because tag helpers internally fire the same html helper method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was using Asp.NET Core Version 1.0.0 (using .net framework 4.6.1 as dependency) and DisplayName was not working (it was rendering the the property name instead of the DisplayName value). I upgraded my MVC packages to 1.1.0-preview1-final and it was solved.

It seems to me there was a bug and they are fixing it in the next version(s). I will keep developing using the previews as I use the DisplayName for extending DisplayAttribute as well.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0-preview1-final", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0-preview1-final"` in `project.json`

Comment: I am using AspNetCore RC2 which is preview2. And, I thought something that is resolved in preview1 would be working fine in preview2. But, it's not working in preview2. Any pointers?

Comment: I did not continue using these previews, They are full of bugs and I expected faster update from M$. I am waiting for official release. I thinks it is better to report a bug in their github.